# problem in passing data when pop from one view to another view controller in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am having a application in which one view controller is pushed and when we pop from the pushed controller i do not get the value for the variable

For eg  consider  there is  A controller i n which i am havinh the int variable named Component now i push to B Controller on click event of button from A Controller ,When we are pushed to B view there is Table View and when i select any of the cell i just pass  indexpath.row value to the int component and here i print value of component value which is correct  , now when its pop to A controller again i print the value of component which comes to be 0(zero) always..
Where am i wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code I would say that you haven't set up a reference to controller A in controller B so when you are calling A.someInt = 5 nothing is happening. Unlink other languages, calling a method on a nil reference just returns nil. It doesn't throw an error.

Comment: here i am setting reference for controller A in Controller B by alloc ing it and in B controller class when i print value of A.component =[indexPath.row  ] , it is correctly printing the value of A.component and when View will Appear Method  of A controller when i print the value component it is null ..

Comment: You shouldn't be allocing a new instance of A. What you're doing is setting the value in the new instance not the old one.

Comment: ya i tried without allocing the A controller in B but didnt get the value  , sorry if my question is too basic